# Cocos2d / Box2d - Animated 'snap to grid' effect

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm playing around with cocos2d and box2d, trying to develop a game where tiles are slid around in a grid.

It's all gone fairly well so far, but i'm try to achieve a 'snap to grid' effect on the tiles after they've been moved by the user, where the tile animates into the correct position, but then briefly oscillates around the correct position, as it 'settles' into place.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how best to achieve this? I've tried using distance joints, and experimenting with the frequency and damping ratio, but to achieve the effect i'd need to reduce the length of the joint down to 0, as the tile body snaps into place. Is this possible with a distance joint, and would doing so actually 'pull' the tile body into place?

Any ideas on how best to approach this would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we didn't use box2d at all, as we seemed to be fighting its physics world, more than using its features.

The tiles were coded to simply follow a drag on the screen, and while sadly we never did manage to achieve the oscillation effect with the snap to, we did manage to  get a 'squashing' effect instead. By having a margin between tiles, and allowing them to move over into another tile's 'space' before a collision detection began, and then springing back into their correct places when the user released the drag.